# Have the following array merged

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, data-structures

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 1
            [Quantity] => 55
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 1
            [Quantity] => 55
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 1
            [Quantity] => 55
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 3
            [Quantity] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 3
            [Quantity] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 3
            [Quantity] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 4
            [Quantity] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 4
            [Quantity] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 4
            [Quantity] => 
        )

)
```

Which is being created with the following code:

```
$Display_Arr = array();
        $Tick = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['product'] AS $_1){
        if (!in_array($_1['vendor_id'], $Display_Arr)){
            $Display_Arr[$Tick] = array(
                "Vendor_ID" => $_1['vendor_id'],
                "Quantity" => ""
            );
            $Display_Arr[$Tick]["Quantity"] .= $_1['quantity']; 
        }else{
            $Display_Arr[$Tick]["Quantity"] .= $_1['quantity']; 
        }
        ++$Tick;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Display_Arr);
    echo "</pre>";
```

But I am not getting my desired output, which is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 1
            [Quantity] => 55,55,55
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 3
            [Quantity] => 
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 4
            [Quantity] => 
        )

)
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

@mathielo

The current output is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 1
            [Quantity] => 55
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 3
            [Quantity] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 4
            [Quantity] => 
        )

)
```

Whereas, i'm trying to obtain:

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Vendor_ID] => 1
            [Quantity] => 55,55,55
        )
```

Comment: what is the actual output?

Comment: @kennypu Output is the first array

Comment: @kennypu Well, let me rephrase. What am I doing wrong within my PHP code to not get my desired output (the second exampled array)

Comment: See $Trick is incremented after each iteration irrespective of the key!! So even if vendoe_ID is the exists the quality cant be appended to the existing array.

Comment: are trying to concat the value? `$Display_Arr[$Tick]["Quantity"] .= $_1['quantity'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, what you need is this:

---

**EDIT:** Just made some tests and got it right this time:

```
$Display_Arr = array();
foreach ($_POST['product'] AS $_1){
    if (!array_key_exists($_1['Vendor_ID'], $Display_Arr)){
        $Display_Arr[$_1['Vendor_ID']] = array(
            "Vendor_ID" => $_1['Vendor_ID'],
            "Quantity" => $_1['Quantity']
        );
    }else{
        if(!empty($_1['Quantity']))
            $Display_Arr[$_1['Vendor_ID']]["Quantity"] .= ",{$_1['Quantity']}"; 
    }

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($Display_Arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

The main problem was in `if (!in_array($_1['vendor_id'], $Display_Arr))`. PHP's `in_array()` checks for given `needle` in the array *values*, and we were trying to match to the `Vendor_ID` value stored in the outer array *keys*. That was fixed using `array_key_exists()`.

**EDIT 2:** I used this for test data:

```
$_POST['product'] = array(
    0 => array(
        'Vendor_ID' => 1,
        'Quantity' => 55
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Vendor_ID' => 1,
        'Quantity' => 55
    ),
    2 => array(
        'Vendor_ID' => 1,
        'Quantity' => 55
    )
    ,
    3 => array(
        'Vendor_ID' => 3,
        'Quantity' => ''
    ),
    4 => array(
        'Vendor_ID' => 3,
        'Quantity' => ''
    ),
    5 => array(
        'Vendor_ID' => 3,
        'Quantity' => ''
    ),
    6 => array(
        'Vendor_ID' => 4,
        'Quantity' => ''
    ),
    7 => array(
        'Vendor_ID' => 4,
        'Quantity' => ''
    ),
    8 => array(
        'Vendor_ID' => 4,
        'Quantity' => ''
    )
);
```

---

You won't be needing `$Tick` anymore, as you could use `Vendor_ID` as keys for the outer array.

Comment: It's only inputting the final digit, not the entire 3 numbers

Comment: @SophieMackeral Please show me the output. I just updated the code with a minor fix, so give it another try.

Comment: @SophieMackeral Is it important to you to keep the outer array keys as 0, 1, 2 using `$Tick`? (I'm doing some tests here)

Comment: Aslong as the necessary information such as the quantities is merged commar seperated within the same array with vendor_id

Comment: @SophieMackeral Just edited my answer - I think we nailed it this time ;)

Comment: Unfortunately no, It's just given a blank multi-dimensional array: http://pastebin.com/JDbX2tLj

Comment: Also added a `if(!empty($_1['Quantity']))` validation to prevent "storing" empty values, which would result in `,,,` occasionally.

Comment: Notice that I've changed the keys of your `$_1` variables from `lowercase`. Maybe your `$_POST` data differs from the first array you posted, so you'll need to change `$_1['Vendor_ID']` for `$_1['vendor_id']`. Same goes for `Quantity` => `quantity`.

Comment: Marked this as the answer, instead of having commer seperated values, i've changed it into a multi-dimensional array by: `"Quantity" => array ( $_1['quantity'])`  and with the else: `$Display_Arr[$_1['vendor_id']]["Quantity"][] = $_1['quantity'];` Which will do just aswell for validations! Thanks for your help

Comment: @SophieMackeral alright! The important thing is that you got what you needed :) Glad I could help.

Comment: Apparent problem, which I can figure out in the morning. "Vendor_ID" is not displayed within the array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37982/discussion-between-mathielo-and-sophie-mackeral)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the easiest way to solve this would be to first aggregate the vendor quantities, and then build the final array with the keys that you are using.

I am assuming the input looks something like this:

```
$_POST['product'] = [
    ['vendor_id' => 1, 'quantity' => 55],
    ['vendor_id' => 1, 'quantity' => 55],
    ['vendor_id' => 1, 'quantity' => 55],
    ['vendor_id' => 3, 'quantity' => null],
    ['vendor_id' => 3, 'quantity' => null],
    ['vendor_id' => 3, 'quantity' => null],
    ['vendor_id' => 4, 'quantity' => null],
    ['vendor_id' => 4, 'quantity' => null],
    ['vendor_id' => 4, 'quantity' => null],
];
```

Aggregating the quantities:

```
$aggregates = [];
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $product) {
    $id = $product['vendor_id'];
    if ( ! isset($aggregates[$id])) {
        $aggregates[$id] = [];
    }
    if ($product['quantity'] > 0) {
        $aggregates[$id][] = $product['quantity'];
    }
}
```

The aggregates array should now look like this:

```
$aggregates = [
    1 => [
        0 => 55,
        1 => 55,
        2 => 55,
    ],
    3 => [], // Empty
    4 => [], // Empty
];
```

As you can see the data is now neatly organized and ready to be put into any format you want. Using the keys that you use in your question it is as simple as:

```
$output = [];
foreach ($aggregates as $vid => $qty) {
    $quantity = implode(',', $qty);
    $output[] = ['Vendor_ID' => $vid, 'Quantity' => $quantity];
}
```

The output should now look like this:

```
$output = [
    ['Vendor_ID' => 1, 'Quantity' => '55,55,55'],
    ['Vendor_ID' => 3, 'Quantity' => ''],
    ['Vendor_ID' => 4, 'Quantity' => ''],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will output exactly what you are looking for although the output of the last answer (Sverri M. Olsen) is more useful. Here you get the quantities as a string while with Sverri's method you get an array in first place.

```
$Display_Arr = array();
$vendors=array();
foreach ($_POST['product'] AS $_1){

  if (!in_array($_1['vendor_id'],$vendors)){
    $vendors[]=$_1['vendor_id'];
    $Display_Arr[sizeof($vendors)-1] = array(
      "Vendor_ID" => $_1['vendor_id'],
      "Quantity" => $_1['quantity']
    );
  }
  else{
    $vendorKey=array_search($_1['vendor_id'],$vendors);
    $Display_Arr[$vendorKey]["Quantity"] .=(!empty($Display_Arr[$vendorKey]["Quantity"])?',':null).$_1['quantity'];
  }
}
```